# Complementary filter and atan2 discontinuity

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have been playing with the iPhone gyroscope and accelerometer and trying to crate an accurate measurement of the device rotation by using both sensors.

First I calculate the devices anglular velocity using the gyroscope, then I find the angle using the accelerometer (by finding where the gravity is pointing, then using atan2). Then I use them to create a nice estimate of the angle using this formula:

```
accAngle = atan2f(yAcceleration, xAcceleration); // reading from accelerometer
gyroAngle = gyroVelocity * timeSinceUpdate; // reading from gyroscope
estimatedAngle = 0.97 * (estimatedAngle + gyroAngle) + 0.03 * accAngle; // filtered angle
```

I then use estimatedAngle to rotate a CALayer.

It works like a charm until the device is turned sideways, and the atan2 function jumps from -pi to pi and back. This discontinuity makes the angle jitter around, and since the angle measure jumps so much, it confuses the filter. I've tried to think of a solution to this but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Any luck on this... I am also looking similar functionality using complementary filter.